# How to pass parameters to Hudson job's shell commands

Tags: jenkins, hudson, parameter-passing

I have a Hudson job that execute shell script on a remote server.

Its shell command is:

```
/usr/bin/deployWar.sh ${warfileName}
```

I marked this build as parameterized, and added a string parameter:

```
name: warFileName
default value: none
description: name of war file
```

When I run it, the parameter gets assigned, but it get passed into the shell script.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) Jenkins plugin documentation states that

> all the environment variables added by parameters are in **upper case**

In your case this should work:

```
/usr/bin/deployWar.sh ${WARFILENAME}
```

Comment: I see that jenkins dont touch the case. If I give a lower-case parameter it will remains lower-case variable

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your approach. How do you know it's not passed to the shell script? The console log will show the "execute shell" command line.

Please paste the whole console log in here

Answer (score 0):

For me the accepted answer did not work. ${WARFILENAME} using the brackets did not find the parameter. The way it seems to work only for shell scripts execution in Jenkins is **$WARFILENAME** (without the brackets).

[This tutorial](https://geekdudes.wordpress.com/2019/08/02/jenkins-run-shell-script-add-parameters-to-job/) helped.

Everywhere else in jenkins options used ${WARFILENAME}.