# How to use Jenkins parameters in a shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I want to use the parameters that we define in the Jenkins job as arguments to the shell commands in the same job.

I have created a parameterized build with the following parameters:

```
high.version: 234
low.version: 220
```

I want to use these variables as arguments for the build's shell script:

```
/bin/bash /hai/mycode/scripts/run_script.sh high.version
```

How do I these parameters in the same job?

Answer (score 20):

Jenkins **will create environment variables** with the parameters' names.

The caveat here is that Jenkins will *also* do that for parameters that do not represent valid variable names -- those are difficult to access in `bash`. This is the case in your example, as `bash` variable names must not contain the `.` character.

The easiest solution is that you

- **rename your parameters**, e.g. to `high_version` and `low_version` (which are valid `bash` variable names)
- then use the corresponding variable names when calling your script

Example:

```
/bin/bash /hai/mycode/scripts/run_script.sh "$high_version"
```

**If you cannot rename parameters** to represent valid `bash` variable names  (e.g., for usability reasons: Jenkins presents variable names to end users in the Web form for starting a build): you can still access such parameters by **grepping for the parameter name in the output of the `env` command**.

Answer (score 17):

What really helped me was [Hudson: How to pass parameters to shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828613/hudson-how-to-pass-parameters-to-shell-script)

Solution: the variables are UPPERCASE even you define them in lowercase!

Comment: It looks like meanwhile they changed it and the variables are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, as of 2.210 (at least, that's the version I'm running), parameters are turned into variables without modifying . That is, I created a parameter named "choice" and was able to `echo $choice` and see the value of my parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use following syntax to pass jenkins parameter to shell script -

eg. **YourScript.sh %JENKINS_PARAMETER%**
after that in your script,you can use that parameter like normal shell script command line parameter.
eg. **myParam = $1**;

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to have `dot(.)` in your parameters. You should either choose `highVersion` OR `high_version` as your param names.

As per your question, it seems that you're working with a `Freestyle` job but many devs coming here would also be interested in the `Pipeline` syntax as well, so I'm giving a solution to use params in `Jenkins pipeline DSL`.
There are two ways you can use Jenkins parameters in the `Jenkins Pipeline` shell script -

1. As a Shell parameter

```
stage('Test'){
  sh "/bin/bash /hai/mycode/scripts/run_script.sh $highVersion"
}
```

2. As a Groovy parameter

```
stage('Test'){
  sh "/bin/bash /hai/mycode/scripts/run_script.sh ${params.highVersion}"
}
```

I would recommend to use a second method, as we're using groovy as a pipeline DSL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
echo "function hello() {   " > gg.sh
echo "echo \$1">> gg.sh
echo "}" >> gg.sh
echo "hello \$1"  >> gg.sh
chmod 777 gg.sh

./gg.sh $hello_version
```

Be careful of the variable name, dot is not that well supported, for detail, you can ref this. 
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7180